# Creating a java main class to convert simple UML to java code

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I've made a basic UML diagram and output file which is just a simple file about preferences of a car; they are as follows

### CarUML.txt

## Car

- cost : int
- color : String
- make : String

  ## + count : int

## + Car ( int cost )

### Car.java

```
package car;

public class Car {
  private int cost;
  private String color;
  private String make;
  public int count;

  public Car (int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
  }

}
```

---

Can anyone just make a simple class which converts the original UML to make the output java file? eg just if + then public, if - then private, etc etc? as these 2 themselves are obviously very simple but I want to make a class where the UML is the input and Car.java is the output?

Thanks

Comment: I recently read something about textual UML which has a defined syntax. I can't recall where but Google is your friend. Anyway you can do what @npinti suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a program which makes use of regular expressions and parse the file one line at a time. So if you have a file of this structure:

```
Car
    cost: int
    color: String
    make: String
    +count: int
```

You could use a regular expressions such as:

- `(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$)` to get the class name: This would yield `public class <group content>`.
- `^([a-zA-z0-9_]+)\s+:\s+(([a-zA-z0-9_]+))$`: This would yield `private <group 2> <group 1>;`.
- `^\+([a-zA-z0-9_]+)\s+:\s+(([a-zA-z0-9_]+))$`: This would yield `public<group 2> <group 1>;`.

For methods, you could use the same, with the only exception that you check for brackets:

- `^([a-zA-z0-9_]+\(\))\s+:\s+(([a-zA-z0-9_]+))$`: This would yield `private <group 2> <group 1>{}`.
- `^\+([a-zA-z0-9_]+\(\))\s+:\s+(([a-zA-z0-9_]+))$`: This would yield `public <group 2> <group 1>{}`.

You could have a dictionary which holds the variable name and type for each of your public fields. These would in turn be included in the automatically generated constructor.

Note though that Java has a default class accessor already. So it might be less confusing to denote private fields by other characters, such as `-` for private fields and `*` for protected.

The regular expressions I have provided should get you started. Ideally you would take a look at the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) to see what constitutes a valid name for each respective data type.